# jQuery .ajax query to insert data inside a database is not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am building a website that uses jQuery/AJAX to send data to a php page, and from there insert it into a database. For some reason, the code isn't inserted and I get no response at all.

my javascript:

```
    function insert_data(){
    var title = debate_title.value;
    var subtitle = debate_sub.value;
    var sides = debate_sides.value;

    $(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
                if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                    window.location.replace('errors/noConnection.html');
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                    window.location.replace('errors/noConnection.html');
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                    window.location.replace('errors/noConnection.html');
                } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                    window.location.replace('errors/noConnection.html');
                } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                    window.location.replace('errors/noConnection.html');
                } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                    window.location.replace('errors/noConnection.html');
                } else {
                    window.location.replace('errors/noConnection.html');
                }
            }
        });
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "post_debate.php",
        data: { post_title: title, post_sub: subtitle, post_sides: sidesm, ajax: 1 },
        dataType: "json",
        timeout: 5000, // in milliseconds
        success: function(data) {
            if(data!==null){
                window.location.replace('show_debate.php?id=' + data);
            }else{
                window.location.replace('errors/noConnection.html');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

My PHP code (post_debate.php):

```
    <?php

    require('connect.php');

    $title = $_POST['post_title'];

    $subtitle = $_POST['post_sub'];

    $sides = $_POST['post_sides'];

    $ajax = $_POST['ajax'];

    $date = new DateTime();
    $timeStamp = $date->getTimeStamp();

    if($ajax==1){
        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO debates VALUES('','$title','$subtitle','$sides','0','0','$timeStamp')");
        $get_data = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM debates WHERE title='$title', subtitle='$subtitle', sides='$sides', timestamp='$timeStamp'");
        while($id=mysql_fetch_array($get_data)){
            $final_id = $id['id'];
        }
        exit($final_id);
    }else{
        die("404 SERVER ERROR");
    }

?>
```

Thanks!

---

**EDIT - NOT SOLVED YET**

My new PHP code:

```
<?php
header("content-type: application/json");

require('connect.php');

$title = $_POST['post_title'];

$subtitle = $_POST['post_sub'];

$sides = $_POST['post_sides'];

$ajax = $_POST['ajax'];

$date = new DateTime();
$timeStamp = $date->getTimeStamp();

if($ajax==1){
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO debates VALUES('','$title','$subtitle','$sides','0','0','$timeStamp')");
    $get_data = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM debates WHERE title='$title', subtitle='$subtitle', sides='$sides', timestamp='$timeStamp'");
    while($id=mysql_fetch_array($get_data)){
        $final_id = $id['id'];
    }
    print (json_encode(array("Id"=>$final_id)));
}else{
    die("404 SERVER ERROR");
}
```

?>

my new Javascript .ajax:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "post_debate.php",
    data: { post_title: title, post_sub: subtitle, post_sides: sides, ajax: 1 },
    dataType: "json",
    timeout: 5000, // in milliseconds
    success: function(data) {
        if(data!==null){
            window.location.replace('show_debate.php?id=' + data['Id']);
        }else{
            window.location.replace('errors/noConnection.html');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: in success: function(data) try doing an alert(data) and post what is in data

Comment: Use your browser's development tools to check that there are no errors with your JavaScript code and that the AJAX request is being made.

Comment: Also, be aware you're using string concatenation to generate your SQL - what happens if any of your data fields contains an apostrophe? Anyone could run _any_ code against your database. Remember [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Thanks @AnthonyGrist, i found a typo this way. But im still in some trouble - please look at the answer below (basic).

Comment: @arielschon12 I'm not a PHP programmer, so can't help you with any server-side code issues. I'd use the browser development tools again to check that the response you're actually sending is what you're expecting to be sent.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist It seems as if my .ajaxSetup is throwing an parse exception.. Any idea why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is expecting JSON as a response...

```
dataType: "json",
```

([Documentation Here](http://docs.jquery.com/Specifying_the_Data_Type_for_AJAX_Requests))

But you're returning a non-json value without an appropriate content-type header.

Try changing your PHP script from

```
   exit($final_id);
```

to (untested)

```
header("content-type: application/json");
print (json_encode(array(
        "Id"=>$final_id
    )));
```

Also, put a breakpoint on your `success` callback in your Javascript code (using Firebug or a similar tool) and examine what `data` contains. It should now be an associative array so you can do

```
window.location.replace('show_debate.php?id=' + data['Id']);
```

#### Improvement:

Instead of doing a SELECT to get the recently inserted Id, use [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php). Something like this...

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO debates VALUES('','$title','$subtitle','$sides','0','0','$timeStamp')");
$final_id = mysql_insert_id();
print (json_encode(array("Id"=>$final_id)));
```

Also, an alternate way to test what your PHP is returning if you can't see the response in your development tool is to browse to the page directly (You'd have to change all your `$_POST` to `$_REQUEST`)

Comment: Ok, so i did this and now i can see that the data gets into my database. However, my success function gets a null data (moves to the else statement in the success) - so i get redirected to the wrong place! Why is this?

Comment: Ok, go to the "Net" tab in your debugger and look at the response coming from your script - is it Valid JSON with the correct headers?

Comment: I am using chrome and the javascript console.. How can i do this?

Comment: In Chrome on Windows, press F12 and one of the tabs should be "Network". If you're on a Mac, I think you can get the same by going to the console tab and finding the request

Comment: Ok, so when going to the network tab i saw that i got redirected to my error page "noConnection.html" because of a parse error, as setup in the .ajaxSetup();. What kind of parse error do i have here?

Comment: It's impossible to know without seeing what your PHP script is returning. Look at the request which goes to your PHP script, expand it, click on the JSON or Response tab and see what it says...

Comment: Checked it and found an error in my query, THANK YOU SO MUCH! i typed these "," instead of AND statements XD

Comment: You're welcome - but look at my edited answer under "Improvement" - That whole step is redundant...